# How to implement click event of button of list view in onPostExecute?

Tags: android

I have list view that is populated with json data in onPostExecute of asynctask in my fragment

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), branchList,
                R.layout.list_branch_total_hours,
                new String[] {  TAG_BRANCHID, TAG_BRANCH_NM,TAG_BRANCHCODE,TAG_REGIONID,TAG_REGION_NAME,TAG_TOT_HR }, new int[]
                {
                R.id.hdnBranchId,R.id.btnBranch_nm, R.id.hdnBranchCode,
                R.id.hdnRegionId,R.id.hdnRegionNm, R.id.btnTot_Hours}
        );
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now i Have button controls in the list..so how i implement click event of the buttons???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: override getView() method of Adapter class and register click on Button.

Comment: can i override that method in my onpostExecute???or I have to make custom adapter??

Answer (score 0):

you can use `

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), branchList,
                R.layout.list_branch_total_hours,
                new String[] {  TAG_BRANCHID, TAG_BRANCH_NM,TAG_BRANCHCODE,TAG_REGIONID,TAG_REGION_NAME,TAG_TOT_HR }, new int[]
                {
                R.id.hdnBranchId,R.id.btnBranch_nm, R.id.hdnBranchCode,
                R.id.hdnRegionId,R.id.hdnRegionNm, R.id.btnTot_Hours}
        )
{
override method here//
public void getView(...
};
        list.setAdapter(adapter);`
```

Comment: I cant override that method in onpostExecute of asynctask